# How to import sqlite database from sdcard to android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to import sqlite database from sdcard to android application, but existing database should have deleted. 
I created one application, but it will not be deleted old database. it is remains still. it is not uploded new one database.

How to deleted previous one & uploaded new one with copy and open database refreshing reflected data.

Please help me

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: your question is confusing , do you want to import  or copy or delete a database

Comment: @Arju i want to import database from sdcard but it should delete all data from old database, & copy all data to to existing database

Comment: http://limbaniandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/useing-your-sqlite-database-in-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);` to delete the existing database.

copy the db using I/O operations and then rename db if you need .

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file, using standard Java file I/O. Make sure that you do not have an open `SQLiteDatabase` or `SQLiteOpenHelper` on the old database before doing the copy. The default location of the database can be found by calling `getDatabasePath()` on any `Context`, such as an `Activity`.